# The Simplest Fraction for a Decimal

Tags: fractions

Is there a way to find the simplest fraction for a decimal?

For example, let us say that I am trying to find the simplest fraction that rounds to $93\%$.
I could easily say that $\frac{93}{100} = 0.93 = 93\%$.
However, this misses $\frac{13}{14} = 0.92857... = \sim93\%$ and $\frac{14}{15} = 0.93333... = \sim93\%$.
Is there a way for me to find $\frac{13}{14}$ and $\frac{14}{15}$ without manually calculating each fraction?

Comment: See [Continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).   [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Convergents%5B.93%2C10%5D) is how that technique handles $.93$  You'll see that it finds $\frac {13}{14}$ but ignores $\frac {14}{15}$ since $15>14$ and the former fraction is a better approximation.

Comment: Please define "simplest fraction".

Comment: @lulu:  continued fractions would suggest $\frac{19}{20}$ for $0.95$ even though $\frac{18}{19} \approx 0.947$ rounds to $0.95$

Comment: @Henry  Good point.

Comment: @Blue, I think the op means the fraction with the smallest positive denominator whose value is in $[0.925,0.935)$.

Comment: @Zuriel: Well, *I* think so too, but what *we* think doesn't matter. :)

Comment: @Blue The definition provided by Zuriel is a good start.